# Inverse of a specific strictly increasing polynomial

Tags: polynomials, inverse, inverse-function

I have the following $(2n-1)$th degree polynomial of $x$: $$y=f(x)=x(x^2+x+1)^{n-1}; n>0$$
The polynomial $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and has only one real root in $0$. Is that possible to analytically find the inverse of this polynomial for a given $n$?

I have suggested this polynomial because it is strictly increasing and has only one real root in $0$. I need these specifications. Do you know how to design a polynomial with these properties which its inverse can be calculated easily?

Comment: Probably not. If you [edit] the question to tell us what you mean by "analytically" and why you need to know we might be able to help, or give a definitive negative answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker I don't want to use numerical optimization to find $x$ for a given $y$. I prefer to find the inverse to easily calculate $x$ for different values of $y$.

Comment: @EthanBolker the polynomial $f(x)$ must be strictly increasing and the only real root is $0$. Is there any other polynomial with this specification which its inverse can be calculated easily?

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial is of degree $(2n-1)$; so, impossible to find its inverse as soon as $n \geq 3$.

However, for *small enough* values of $x$, we could expand as Taylor series to get
$$y=x+(n-1) x^2+\frac{1}{2} (n-1) n x^3+\frac{1}{6} \left(n^3-7 n+6\right)
   x^4+\frac{1}{24} \left(n^4+2 n^3-25 n^2+46 n-24\right) x^5+\frac{1}{120} n
   \left(n^4+5 n^3-55 n^2+115 n-66\right) x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$$ and use [series reversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to get
$$x=y+(1-n) y^2+\frac{1}{2} \left(3 n^2-7 n+4\right) y^3-\frac{2}{3} \left(4 n^3-15
   n^2+17 n-6\right) y^4+\frac{1}{24} \left(125 n^4-650 n^3+1135 n^2-826
   n+216\right) y^5+\frac{1}{10} \left(-108 n^5+720 n^4-1725 n^3+1930 n^2-1027
   n+210\right) y^6+O\left(y^7\right)$$

Comment: an approximate solution is also valuable. Many thanks.

Comment: @MehdiMoghadasian. In terms of approximation, we could do it better using the inverse series to build some $[k+1,k]$ Padé approximant which would be $O(y^{2k+2})$.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici. Is there any way to design a series (with positive integer powers) which its inverse can be calculated exactly by means of series reversion?

Comment: @MehdiMoghadasian. I do not see what you are meaning. Could you clarify, please ?

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici. Actually, the polynomial in the question is not the only choice. I only need a polynomial (or power series) which its inverse can be calculated exactly. I suggested $x(x^2+x+1)^{n-1}$ because it was strictly increasing. I was asking if there may be a specific type of power series which its inverse can be calculated exactly.